# Posggresql cannot load hstore.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using ruby on `rails 5.2.2.1` and `posgresql 11.2` on `Mac OsX 10.14.3`, I am getting the follow error when I run a test

```
 --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::InternalError:
     #   ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/hstore.so": dlopen(/usr/local/lib/postgresql/hstore.so, 10): Symbol not found: _lookup_rowtype_tupdesc_domain
     #     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/postgresql/hstore.so
     #     Expected in: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/bin/postgres
     #    in /usr/local/lib/postgresql/hstore.so
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reinstall `PostgreSQL`. See issue [Postgis library not loaded error #46358](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/46358)

```
brew update; brew reinstall postgresql;
```

It is not necessary to reinstall `postgist` as the post suggest if you are not using it.